# When unittesting with Flask, Flask-SQLAlchemy, and SQLAlchemy, how do I isolate test databases between threads?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Suppose I'm following the [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/quickstart/) quickstart example, and I want to add a couple of unittests.

My model might look something like:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
Base = db.Model

class Account(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(1000))
```

For unittesting, I'll want to create and destroy a database for each test.

```
def _setup_database():
    db_name = 'test_%s' % random.randint(0,999999)

    # (Code that creates database with db_name and setups the schema)

    app.config['DB_NAME'] = db_name
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql:///{}'.format(db_name)


def _destroy_db():
    db_name = app.config['DB_NAME']

    # Code that destroys the test db


class TestAccounts(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        _setup_database()

    def tearDown(self):
        _destroy_db()

    def test_new_signup(self):
        account = models.Account(...)

    def test_something_else(self):
        account = models.Account(...)
```

The problem here is that, if I run this code in an environment where unittests are multi-threaded, there is a race condition. Two databases are usually setup simultaneously and app.config is pointed to one of them.

If I were using SQLAlchemy directly, I would create a new session for each test and use that session. But Flask-SQLAlchemy creates sessions for me, and as such, seems to depend on having one global `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']` to point to a database.

What's the right way to create test databases and point a test thread to them with Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Comment: Don't have an answer but curious as to why you are doing multithreaded tests? Seems like an unnecessary layer of complexity.

Comment: @Adam It results in tests getting done a lot faster. Don't most people use multiple threads for unit tests?

Comment: I've never done it. My work doesn't have a robust CI/testing regimen in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With unittest `TestCase.setUp` and `TestCase.tearDown` are run for each `test_` functions.

So running your test in multithreaded process will indeed create a race condition. You need to either run your test in a single thread. Which will fix the race condition, but you'll still create and destroy the all database for each test which is unnecessary and slow.

A better solution is to use the [`setUpclass` and `tearDownClass`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass) methods, which only run once per test class.

If you need to run this fixtures for all classes in a module there is also `setUpModule` and `tearDownModule`.

If you need to set fixtures for the full session now you have a problem... IMHO that is the time to switch to pytest.